# Creating editable copy of a dataset while keeping the original intact using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, dataset

I have recently started studying machine learning and am focusing on the pre-processing stage. I'm creating a Jupyter Notebook which lays out the stages of pre-processing step by step. The original dataset has some missing values in it which I will replace with the mean value. As it is a step by step notebook I am creating, I would like to be able to keep the original dataset in tact while having a copy of the dataset which will be updated at different steps of the process i.e. missing cells will be replaced with the mean values. See the code below for what I have done so far. It does what I want it to do so far, it's just missing the copied dataset part.

Any tips or links to tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

#Importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

# Splitting the attributes into independent and dependent attributes
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values # attributes to determine dependent variable
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values # dependent variable / Class variable, final column


#printing and displaying dataset
print(dataset)
display(dataset.describe())

#check how many null values in dataset and output value
print('Number of null/NaN values in dataset: ',dataset.isnull().values.sum())

#show how many null values per column
print(dataset.isnull().sum())

#DEALING WITH MISSING VALUES USING MEAN
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

#creating SimpleImputer object, specifying to change missing values to mean
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')

#MEAN
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 3:4])
X[:,3:4] = imputer.transform(X[:,3:4])

print(X)
```

Comment: I am not sure, what you want exactly. But what i understand is you need to make a copy of a original_dataframe and use that copy, play with that, without changing the original_dataframe. Is that all you want ? or something else ?

Comment: Yes. So basically, keep the original dataset in tact while having a copy which can be updated as I progress to show the changes that have been made to the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather prefer to use [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) class in python by calling `deepcopy`

```
import copy
df_edit = copy.deepcopy(df_original)
```

Now you can play with `df_edit` and make your changes without disturbing `df_original`

or

you can directly use [pandas copy module](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) like `df_edit = df_original.copy(deep = True)`

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to create a copy of `dataset` to revert to later?

You could create a chunk in your notebook to back it up e.g.

```
dataset_backup = dataset
```

then another to overwrite dataset with dataset backup

```
dataset = dataset_backup
```

Then run each as and when you want to backup the dataset or revert to the backup

Alternatively, if you want to have a record of dataset at each step in the process   just create a new variable for it each time e.g. `dataset_means` this is usually a good idea for debugging purposes.

Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Thanks Alex. How would I go about overwriting the dataset after I have ran the impute code which replaces the null values? I'm fairly new to Python so it's probably something simple.

Comment: something like ```imputer = Imputer()``` then ```dataset_imputed = Imputer.fit(X)```? Im not familiar with scikit learn but you just want to assign it to a variable